# Show that $(X_{k_1}^{a_1},...,X_{k_s}^{a_s})$ is $(X_{k_1},...,X_{k_s})$-primary

Tags: abstract-algebra, monomial-ideals, ideals

> Show that $I=(X_{k_1}^{a_1},...,X_{k_s}^{a_s})$ is $(X_{k_1},...,X_{k_s})$-primary, where $I$ is the ideal generated by the monomials $X_{k_1}^{a_1},...,X_{k_s}^{a_s}$ .

I noticed  that $$\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{({X_{i_1}}^{a_1},...,{X_{i_k}}^{a_k})}=\sqrt{({X_{i_1}}^{a_1})+...+({X_{i_k}}^{a_k})}=\sqrt{\sqrt{(X_{i_1})^{a_1}}+...+\sqrt{(X_{i_k})^{a_k}}}=\sqrt{(X_{i_1})+...+(X_{i_k})}=\sqrt{(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_k})}=(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_k}).$$
I have to show that $I$ is primary, i.e. if $u\cdot v\in I$ then $u\in I$ or $v\in (X_{k_1},...,X_{k_s})$.

Comment: You might take some time improving your question. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No! I want to understand primary decompositions of monomial ideals.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey is this question too easy?

Comment: Not sure as it isn't my area, but whenever someone says "show" it often is homework. I would edit the question specifying what the terms are and add something about why you are interested in this.